# vb6 Multimedia query

Tags: vb6

How can I add an animated file on VB form? What extention does it support?

Comment: I noticed that you have answers to most of your questions.  You might want to accept an answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Animation Control which is part of the MSCOMCT2.OCX file.  It plays silent avi files.  Here's the [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231219%28VS.60%29.aspx) on using the Animation Control.

Code sample:

```
' Code to play an .avi file
Private Sub cmdPlay_Click()
   ' Configure a CommonDialog control to allow the
   ' user to find .avi files to play. The CommonDialog
   ' control is named "dlgOpen." The Animation control
   ' is named "anmAVI."
   dlgOpen.Filter = "avi files (*.avi)|*.avi"
   dlgOpen.ShowOpen
   anmAvi.Open dlgOpen.FileName
   anmAVI.Play
End Sub

' Code to stop play
Private Sub cmdStop_Click()
   anmAVI.Stop
End Sub
```